# Conditionally change angular location strategy

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, hash-location-strategy

I’m trying to replace the location strategy by condition prod/dev

```
console.log(IonicENV.mode) <= this loges true
```

Then

```
 { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: (IonicENV.mode == "prod") ? PathLocationStrateg HashLocationStrategy }
```

Although IonicEnv.mode returns prod, so the condition is true. but it always goes into using HashlocationStrategy.
There is no logical explanation at all…

if I do

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: (console.log(IonicENV.mode == "prod")) ? PathLocationStrategy : HashLocationStrategy }
```

Then everything works correctly on the server. it meets the true condition and goes into using pathLocationStrategy… Any explanations…anyone??

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` always return `undefined` and `!!undefined` is `false`. So

```
(console.log(IonicENV.mode == "prod")) ? PathLocationStrategy : HashLocationStratege
```

is the same as

```
(false) ? PathLocationStrategy : HashLocationStratege // because of braces
```

and is the same as `HashLocationStratege`

Comment: but it did use PAthlocationStrategy when I wrap it using console log, so it was true

Comment: but `{ useClass: (console.log("prod" == "prod")) ? 0 : 1 }` == `{ useClass: 1 }` also `{ useClass: (console.log("notProd" == "prod")) ? 0 : 1 }` == `{ useClass: 1 }` so in second case it must be `HashLocationStrategy`